# Columns cannot bound in Joins

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to calculate the leaves taken by employee and the addition and deduction in the salary for this month.
I am stuck at this point where I am joining these tables but I am getting error that I can't bound one of the column from table I specified in `FROM` clause.

Here is my query, If someone can help that'd be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
[EI].[FirstName]+' '+[EI].[LastName] [Employee], 
[Addition].[Amount] [AdditionAmount], [AdditionType].[FullName] [AdditionType],
[Deduction].[Amount] [DeductionAmount], [DeductionType].[FullName] [DeductionType],
MONTH([Leave].[ApprovedOn]) AS [Month], Count(*) AS [LeaveTaken]

FROM

[HRM].[tbl_EmployeeSalary] [Salary],
[HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [EI]

FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeLeave] [Leave] ON [EI].[ID] = [Leave].[EmpCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeSalaryAddition] [Addition] ON [Salary].[ID] = [Addition].[EmpSalaryCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_AdditionType] [AdditionType] ON [AdditionType].[ID] = [Addition].[AdditionTypeCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeSalaryDeduction] [Deduction] ON [Salary].[ID] = [Deduction].[EmpSalaryCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_DeductionType] [DeductionType] ON [DeductionType].[ID] = [Deduction].[DeductionTypeCode]


WHERE
MONTH([Leave].[ApprovedOn]) = MONTH(GetDate())

GROUP BY 
[EI].[FirstName]+' '+[EI].[LastName], 
[Addition].[Amount], [AdditionType].[FullName],
[Deduction].[Amount] , [DeductionType].[FullName],
MONTH([Leave].[ApprovedOn])
```

I'm pretty much sure there is some sort of syntax issue like the order I am not able to set. I tried searching the issue but can't figure out in my case.

Comment: You have enough full joins here to take down an entire server farm.  Are you sure you want to be doing all these joins?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes actually,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have table structure still this query will remove your syntactical error

```
SELECT 
[EI].[FirstName]+' '+[EI].[LastName] [Employee], 
[Addition].[Amount] [AdditionAmount], [AdditionType].[FullName] [AdditionType],
[Deduction].[Amount] [DeductionAmount], [DeductionType].[FullName] [DeductionType],
MONTH([Leave].[ApprovedOn]) AS [Month], Count(*) AS [LeaveTaken]
FROM
[HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [EI]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeLeave] [Leave] 
ON [EI].[ID] = [Leave].[EmpCode],
[HRM].[tbl_EmployeeSalary] [Salary]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeSalaryAddition] [Addition] 
ON [Salary].[ID] = [Addition].[EmpSalaryCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_AdditionType] [AdditionType] 
ON [AdditionType].[ID] = [Addition].[AdditionTypeCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeSalaryDeduction] [Deduction] 
ON [Salary].[ID] = [Deduction].[EmpSalaryCode]
FULL JOIN [HRM].[tbl_DeductionType] [DeductionType] 
ON [DeductionType].[ID] = [Deduction].[DeductionTypeCode]
WHERE
MONTH([Leave].[ApprovedOn]) = MONTH(GetDate())
GROUP BY 
[EI].[FirstName]+' '+[EI].[LastName], 
[Addition].[Amount], [AdditionType].[FullName],
[Deduction].[Amount] , [DeductionType].[FullName],
MONTH([Leave].[ApprovedOn])
```

Comment: Yes it did, Thank you